New SSD speed tanks after writing a couple of GBs
My System:

Windows 11 Pro
Intel 13600K
RTX 2080 TI
MAG B660M MORTAR DDR4
Samsung NVME 980 Pro 1TB (Windows)
SEAGATE 1.92TB BarraCuda SATA 3 2.5" ZA1920CV1A002

This brand new SSD - SEAGATE 1.92TB - doesn't really perform how it should or at least I believe so. When I'm trying to write something to the disk the speed always tanks at a certain point. The amount of data which is written at a normal speed before that happens, differs a little every time. This only happens after about 500GB are occupied, when it's empty it runs perfectly fine.
I had the same issue with a NVMe from Crucial, which I returned since I thought it was bad. But I can't imagine getting two duds in a row.
My Samsung SSD seems to be unaffected.
What I checked:

AHCI mode is on
I tried changing APM settings
Windows on best performance
Tried two different PCs plus on Linux and Windows
Also different program for the copy process (Ultracopier)





Is the issue only when there is already data on the SSD, or while writing a large amount of data? If the second, the issue could be overheating.

This is normal. SSDs typically have a faster zone and a slower zone: there are many benchmarks that show it: https://www.techpowerup.com/review/solidigm-p44-pro-2-tb-1-tb/6.html

Per the second duplicate most modern fast SSDs have two types of flash. TLC for bulk storage which is only "kindof" fast for writing but is really fast for reading, and a fast SLC cache which buffers incoming writes. Once the SLC is full then you end up using the slower write speed of the TLC flash.

You've also got SATA SSD vs NVMe that might affect speed. The speeds in the first image are pretty close to the 540/510 MB/s in the spec for the drive.
